# CoreNLP API for N-grams with position

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, n-gram, pos-tagger

Does CoreNLP have an API for getting ngrams with position etc.?

For example, I have a string "I have the best car ". 
if I am using mingrams=1 and maxgrams=2.
I should get the following like below.I know stringutil with ngram function but how to get position.

```
(I,0)
(I have,0)
(have,1)
(have the,1)
(the,2)
(the best,2) etc etc
```

based on the string I am passing.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in the utils.  Here is some sample code to help:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.*; 
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;


public class NGramPositionExample {


    public static List<List<String>> getNGramsPositions(List<String> items, int minSize, int maxSize) {
        List<List<String>> ngrams = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int listSize = items.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) {
        for (int ngramSize = minSize; ngramSize <= maxSize; ++ngramSize) {
        if (i + ngramSize <= listSize) {
            List<String> ngram = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = i; j < i + ngramSize; ++j) {
            ngram.add(items.get(j));
            }
                    ngram.add(Integer.toString(i));
            ngrams.add(ngram);
        }
        }
    }
    return ngrams;
    }


        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
            String testString = "I have the best car";
            List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(testString.split(" "));
            List<List<String>> ngramsAndPositions = getNGramsPositions(tokens,1,2);
            for (List<String> np : ngramsAndPositions) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(np.toArray()));
            }
        }
}
```

You can just cut and paste that utility method.

This might be a useful functionality to add, so I will put this on our list of things to work on.

Answer (score 1):

just spend some code to rewrite it in scala. its just the above code change it to scala. The out put will be like

```
NgramInfo(I,0)NgramInfo(I have,0)NgramInfo(have,1)NgramInfo(have the,1)NgramInfo(the,2)NgramInfo(the best,2)NgramInfo(best,3)NgramInfo(best car,3)NgramInfo(car,4)
```

Below is the method with case class

```
   def getNgramPositions(items: List[String], minSize: Int, maxSize: Int): List[NgramInfo] = {
        var ngramList = new ListBuffer[NgramInfo]
        for (i <- 0 to items.size by 1) {
          for (ngramSize <- minSize until maxSize by 1) {
            if (i + ngramSize <= items.size) {
              var stringList = new ListBuffer[String]
              for (j <- i to i + ngramSize by 1) {
                if (j < items.size) {
                  stringList += items(j)
                  ngramList += new NgramInfo(stringList.mkString(" "), i)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ngramList.toList
      }

case class NgramInfo(term: String, termPosition: Int) extends Serializable
```

Thanks